# Python & Yelp API: how to bypass JSON response LOCATION_NOT_FOUND

Tags: python, json, yelp

I arrive to retrieve JSON from Yelp API.
Problems arrive when I search for a town but that town is not in Yelp database.
In this case I receive a response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "LOCATION_NOT_FOUND",
    "description": "Could not execute search, try specifying a more exact location."
  }
}
```

As I'm searching in bulk I would like to write a statement that says that `if` "LOCATION_NOT_FOUND" is inside my JSON response, do nothing and pass to the next town.

I need something like this:

```
if response_data['error']['code'] == 'LOCATION_NOT_FOUND':
    pass
else:
```

but is not working because it says:

```
if response_data['error']['code'] == 'LOCATION_NOT_FOUND':
KeyError: 'error'
```

this because error is not always there but just when there is no town

Comment: Can you add what you've tried ? And the a global overview of your JSON data ?

Comment: This [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359686/python-parse-json-in-loop/44359775#44359775) was the good one for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first check if there is an error. This can be done using the `key in dict` syntax.

```
if 'error' in response_data:  # Check if there is a key called "error"
    if response_data['error'].get('code') != 'LOCATION_NOT_FOUND':
        # A different code, should probably log this.
        logging.error(json.dumps(response_data))
else:
    # Continue as normal.
```